# Blocking internet access for non-administrative (child) user in Edubuntu

Tags: networking, permissions, internet, edubuntu

I have setup Edubuntu on a laptop (Edubuntu 23.10 Mantic Minotaur). There is an administrative parent account and a (non-administative) child account. Of course, the application management lets me block access to a browser. But I would like to go a step further and disable internet access for the non-administrative user account (for the child) completely. How can I do this?

Edubuntu has an easy interface for hidding applications for non-administrative users.

There is always potentially an application that might give access to the internet. I would like to avoid going through every application running on the non-administrative account.

As an example, I came across a video player (totem), which was included in the basic installation of Edubuntu and allows to download videos if a URL is entered. As there might be other applications, which I do not know in particular and which may give access to doubtful websites, as a precaution, internet access should be disabled for the child completely.

Comment: or change the wifi password :)

Answer (score 5):

Create a file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/99-NM-root.conf` with the following lines:

```
[main]
auth-polkit=root-only
```

Then restart NetworkManager:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Comment: I would like to offer Internet access for some applications, for example Google maps. Unfortunately, the child was able to launch a Wikipedia page in the browser from a link in Google maps. The result was that the child got access to a Firefox browser despite Firefox being blocked in edubuntu control. Google maps was enabled for non-administrative users on purpose.